# How to handle very large drawable files in an Android Application

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable

My client has given me very large resolution images for `background` and `splash`. He insisted that the quality of images should not be compromised.

He is looking to run application on `Samsung Galaxy s5` and other small devices as well.

Now i have `17MB` background image and other high resolution images as well.

I have read about `hdpi`, `ldpi`  and other screen resolution android provided, but i am unable to understand if i put all these images in my `drawabales` then the size of my `apk` file will be so high.

Kindly guide me how do you manage `high resolution` images.

Comment: The highest resolution on mobile devices now is 2k resolution.... so you can reduce the image to 2k resolution and use this singlecimages for all devices since android will scale the large image to fit in small res screens also,,,do not forget to use library like glde to load the images since they have good memory management techniques while inflating the images even on low memory devices

Comment: You don't need to use big image more than 2560x1600 resolution. You can make image smaller if the image is bigger than this resolution. Your client can't notice the difference :)

Comment: but 2500X1600 image will also be around 5-6 mb, so 8 images will be around 40-50mb..

Answer (score 1):

you can resize images as per the densities from android 
[link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

**ldpi** (low) ~120dpi

**mdpi** (medium) ~160dpi

**hdpi** (high) ~240dpi

**xhdpi** (extra-high) ~320dpi

**xxhdpi** (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi

**xxxhdpi** (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Comment: but won't adding multiple image resources increase the size of my `apk` file

Comment: for now you can add hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi !! will do for all the phone as most of phone pick images from them. as well as this will reduce your apk size too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your app to be heavy then you can put these images on the server and then load these images when the activity starts but for that you will be needing internet connection.